# BackboneJS: getting uncaught type error in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backbonejs. I am facing the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function                    backbone.js:26
```

Here is my code

index.php inside script tag

```
<script>
    new App.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();

    App.contacts = new App.Collections.Contacts;
    App.contacts.fetch().then(function () {
        new App.Views.App({ collection: App.contacts });
    });
</script>
```

main.js

```
(function ($) {
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {}
};

window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
})(jQuery);
```

router.js

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '': 'index'
},

index: function () {
    console.log('index page');
}
});
```

collections.js

```
App.Collections.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Contact,
url : '/contacts'
});
```

models.js

```
App.Models.Appoinment = Backbone.Model.extend({
//validate
});
```

views.js

```
//Global App view
App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function () {
    console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
}
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here what I did
Inside collections.js I was pointing to `App.Models.Contact` whereas I did not have this model. I created it and now it works.